# How to get the window title text from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, title

How can I get the value of the current window's `title`, set like this:

```
TITLE Here Are The New Contents
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but you can retrieve it from the `tasklist` command.

`tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /fo list /v`

Comment: How can I get the correct instance of cmd.exe if multiple are running?

Comment: You can run `wmic process get parentprocessid,name|find "WMIC"` which returns the parent PID of the executing instance of cmd.exe. You can then parse the string (perhaps a for loop) to extract the PID and run against tasklist as `tasklist /fi "pid eq <PID>" /fo list /v | find "Window Title:`

Comment: While the command in the answer in combination with the previous comment provide all the _ingredients_ for a complete solution, putting it all together is far from trivial, unfortunately. The next comment summarizes all required steps.

Comment: You need an initial `wmic` call to determine the current `cmd.exe`' instance's PID (process ID), by parsing the `wmic` call's output.
A temporary file is needed, because  direct use of `for /f` with the `wmic` call would run it in a _child_ `cmd.exe` process, which wouldn't work. After parsing the temporary file with `for /f` to extract the PID into variable, that variable can then be used in a `tasklist` call to get information about the current `cmd.exe` instance, including its window title. `tasklist`'s output too must be parsed with `for /f` to extract the window title in isolation.

Answer (score 9):

**In cmd.exe (usual command line prompt):**

*Set window's title:*

```
title "Your New Title"
```

*Get window's title:* I didn't found anything useful to do such thing, However if you have some knowledge with C# or Visual Basic, you can develop a little program that will look in opened windows to find your command line and return the title for you. (using the PID of parent process (your cmd.exe))

**In Powershell:** (things are easy here)

*Set window's title:*

```
[system.console]::title = "Your New Title"
```

*Get window's title:*

```
$myTitleVar = [system.console]::title
```

or you can output it directly:

```
[system.console]::title
```

Comment: `echo [system.console]::title` simply outputs `[system.console]::title` for me

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No need to use `echo` - just submit `[system.console]::title` as-is (PowerShell _implicitly_ outputs [to the display]). If you do use `echo` (which is an alias for `Write-Output`, whose explicit use is rarely needed), you must enclose the argument in `(...)`: `echo ([system.console]::title)` - in command arguments, a token-initial `[` isn't evaluated as an _expression_ and considered a string literal; see [about_Parsing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

Answer (score 4):

**Calling PowerShell** from your batch file  via its CLI, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), is **easiest**:

```sh
:: Outputs the window title.
powershell -noprofile -c [Console]::Title | findstr .
```

Note:

- `[Console]::Title` returns the current console window's title using the [`System.Console`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console) .NET class; PowerShell provides access to *all* .NET types.
- The `findstr .` command is a *dummy* command, which is necessary to prevent the output from containing a  `- <command-line>` suffix, owing to the fact that `cmd.exe` appends such a suffix to the window title while a command line is executing (`<command-line>` here represents the specific command line invoked).
  Appending a suffix does *not* happen if a *pipeline* (`|`) is used, so the addition of `| findstr .` exe - which simply passes (non-empty) output through - is enough to prevent a suffix from showing in the result.

**Complete example** that shows **how to capture the title in a *variable***:

```sh
@echo off & setlocal

:: Assign a custom title.
title This ^& That

:: Retrieve the current title and store it var. %thisTitle%
for /f "delims=" %%t in (
  'powershell -noprofile -c [Console]::Title ^| findstr .'
) do set thisTitle=%%t

echo This window's title: "%thisTitle%"
```

The above yields:

```
This window's title: "This & That"
```

---

**More cumbersome alternative via `wmic` and `tasklist`:**

Note:

- The *ingredients* for this solution are in [AtomicFireball's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1155863/139307) and a comment on it, but how to put them all together may not be obvious. The code below does that.
- As you can see, the solution is much more complex compared to the PowerShell solution; note that using `powershell.exe` with the `-c` (`-Command`) parameter is *not* subject to the infamous PowerShell [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies), so there should be no concern about using PowerShell for this task.

**Complete example** (same output as above):

```sh
:: Assign a custom title.
title This ^& That

:: Find the PID (process ID) of this cmd.exe session.
:: Note: A *temporary file* is required to capture the command output,
::       for later parsing. A `for /f` command cannot be used DIRECTLY
::       because it would execute the command in a *child* cmd.exe process, 
::       which would report the wrong PID.
:: Get a path for a temporary file.
set TEMPFILE=~getpid_%DATE%%TIME%.txt
set TEMPFILE=%TEMPFILE:/=%
set TEMPFILE=%TEMPFILE::=%
set TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\%TEMPFILE: =%
WMIC process get Name,ParentProcessId | findstr "^WMIC\.exe" > "%TEMPFILE%"
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in (%TEMPFILE%) do set PID=%%i
del "%TEMPFILE%"

:: Now use the PID to look up process details, which includes the window title.
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%i in (
  'tasklist /fi "PID eq %PID%" /fo list /v ^| findstr "^Window Title:'
) do set thisTitle=%%j
:: Trim the leading space:
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ("%thisTitle%") do set thisTitle=%%i

echo This window's title: "%thisTitle%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or for short as a batch function:

```
rem # Assign a custom title.
title This ^& That

rem # Retrieve the current title.

CALL :getWindowTitle windowTitle
ECHO windowTitle="%windowTitle%".
GOTO :EOF

:getWindowTitle titlevar
    SETLOCAL
    FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%t IN (`powershell -noprofile -c "[system.console]::title"`) DO SET "thisTitle=%%t"
    ENDLOCAL&CALL SET "%~1=%thisTitle%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

powershell ( Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$PID ).ParentProcessId

Comment: And **then** what?

Comment: tasklist /fi "pid eq 13368"  /fo list /v  | find /i "Window Title:"

Comment: The last command returns: `Window Title: N/A` on Windows 11. Seems that the PowerShell command get the wrong ProcessID