# Testing Command Prompt window title with batch?

Tags: batch, batch-file

Can I test the title of a Command Prompt window?
I know that I can start a .bat file with a title:

```
start "idk_title" cmd /c ".\idk_name.bat"
```

But is there a way that I can test it? Something like this:

```
if title == "idk_title" echo wow the title says idk.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the window title text from batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/1155853/how-to-get-the-window-title-text-from-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

This powershell one liner wrapped in batch should do:

```
powershell -Nop -c "(([system.console]::title) -split ' - powershell')[0]"
```

To save it to a variable

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\12\28\SU_1388261.cmd
@Echo off
Title This is just a test text
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
powershell -Nop -c "(([system.console]::title) -split ' - powershell')[0]"
`) do set "WindowTitle=%%A"
set WindowTitle
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\12\28\SU_1388261.cmd
WindowTitle=This is just a test text
```

Answer (score 0):

download CMDWIZ library,

right there; https://github.com/misol1/gotoxy/blob/master/cmdwiz.exe

and i say, it's working fine!

test;

```
 C:\Users\teo\Desktop | (Teoman)>title as da ds ad as da sda s

 C:\Users\teo\Desktop | (Teoman)>cmdwiz gettitle
 as da ds ad as da sda s - cmdwiz  gettitle
```

for more info about (gettitle) command... write "cmdwiz gettitle /?" if you want to save your title as a value.